# How to get average activity per person per day if a zero-day generates no rows/data?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I'm doing some research regarding activity among subscribers to a website. Specifically, I would like to see the Average Number of Clicks Per Subscriber Per Day in 2018. Unfortunately, the data table provided to me does not account for days when the subscriber does not engage with the website at all, but I need the zero-days factored in.

If I begin my query with something like:

```
SELECT SubscriberID, date_trunc('Day', Date_of_Activity), count(*) as Clicks 
FROM WSD.Clicks 
WHERE Date_Of_Activity between date('2018-01-01') and date('2019-01-01') 
GROUP BY 1,2
```

...each subscriber will only have an entry for a particular calendar day if they had a confirmed click occurred on that date; otherwise, no row would have generated in the source data. This causes inflation in an average because it only accounts for subs when they are active; a person using the website one day in a year with 2 clicks is now equal to a person using it 300 days of the year clicking twice each day. How can I make the query declare a calendar day for every subscriber and ascribe a value of "0" in cases where they actually had no recorded activity?

For reference, this table only has a few columns:

> SubscriberID (string), Date_of_Activity (timestamp), Type_of_Activity
>   (string)

I am querying the data in Athena (AWS).

Comment: I suggest creating a table (probably a temporary table makes sense). Fill it with dates in the range you want. Then join this with a sub query generating all users. Take that result and left join it to the data and count rows.

Comment: Create Calendar table then add join and count day by day subscription

Comment: Note that the BETWEEN condition includes both edges, so your query would also include clicks that happened on January 1st, 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join against a list of dates. This is easily done in Postgres using [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

```
select c.subscriberid, 
       d.day::date as date_of_activity, 
       count(c.date_of_activity) as clicks 
from generate_series(date '2018-01-01', date '2018-12-31', interval '1' day) as d(day)
  left join clicks c on c.date_of_activity::date = d.day::date 
group by 1,2
order by 1,2;
```

`count()` ignores `null` values and the left join will return `null` in the columns of `clicks` when there is no match. So `count(c.Date_Of_Activity)` will return zero for those days.

This will however show empty values for `subscriberid` as well. If you want to create fake rows for each subscriberid/date_of_activity combination, you will need to cross join to a list of all subscribers. Note that this will give you `(number of subscribers) * 365` rows in your result! If you have millions of subscribers this might not be what you want:

```
select s.subscriberid, 
       d.day::date as date_of_activity, 
       count(c.date_of_activity) as clicks 
from generate_series(date '2018-01-01', date '2018-12-31', interval '1' day) as d(day)
  cross join subscribers s
  left join clicks c on c.date_of_activity::date = d.day::date 
group by 1,2
order by 1,2;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/QIGI84548

Comment: Thank you! Generate_series was not supported in Athena, but I was able to generate a total list of dates using the table's date variable as the sole Select item in a subquery. This structure was very helpful.